# Why Copay sends amount from address to address?

Tags: copay

I received a payment to my Copay wallet, and in some reason Copay regularly send it from address to an other address and so forth. I can see it in https://blockchain.info What is the purpose of it? Anyway the balance is slightly falling what irritates me a bit. Why? What is the purpose behind it? Because starting application, because updating iOS?.

Comment: Does this only happen when you use the wallet to make payments? Or are transactions happening that have nothing to do with anything you requested?

Comment: Change address & miner fees?

Answer (score 1):

If you receive a payment in your wallet, it should stay there unless you make any transactions yourself by purpose. Anything else would get me worried to say the least.